# assembler multiple line array+ can't trace in the compiler

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have a project where i manually define a very long array(over 30, every one is a struct object with 2 values). When I define the array in multiple rows I get an error for every row, I don't get the error after I define it one row.how can i write the array in multiple rows?
i have a second problem that when i compile the code

```
include ConIo.h
include Graph.h
start:  mov ax,dseg
        mov ds,ax
        push 12h
        call SetVideoMode
        int 3h
cseg ends
end start
```

Tasm 5.0 writes me a "program has no Symbol table" error and i can't trace to the code.
how can i fix it?
my Cpu is a dual core 1.86 ghz

Comment: you're going to need to be more specific. for which cpu? which compiler? what errors??

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your program with the -v switch in order for TLINK to include the symbol table for debugging. You will also need to include the /zi or /zd in TASM in order for the assembler to include the debugging information.